# How to remove duplicate commits after using git filter-branch?

Tags: git, github

I used the code below to edit my commit history, a wrong email was set to my git config and I wanted to update all my commits with the correct one.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
WRONG_EMAIL="xxx"
NEW_NAME="xxx"
NEW_EMAIL="xxxx"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$WRONG_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$NEW_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$NEW_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

now the problem is it duplicated all the commits, even the ones that are not mine, I would understand that it left my old commits and created a new one but why did it duplicate commits that aren't mine?
could anyone tell me why did this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you missed doing the following

`git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'`

After you changed the commits locally, you should force the update on your remote.

The duplicate is mainly because the old commits on your remote didn't change.

Answer (score -1):

Well, a little semi-technical background is needed to fully understand this...

**tl;dr** - If a commit is rewritten, then every child of that commit must also be rewritten.  So for example it sounds like you had to rewrite the initial commit; that would force rewriting of every commit.  You can't fix it; this is integral to how git works.  If you want to change content in the root commit, you change the hash value for every commit, inescapably.

**Details**:

The structure within a git repo is fairly rigid; this has to do with how git achieves its performance, using hashes for quick content comparisons, etc.  Every object is given a hash value, and that hash value is used to store the object.  This goes for files (called blob objects), directories (tree objects), commits (the objects you're concerned about), and anything else git can store and address.

A strict algorithm calculates the hash, so the same content will always be given the same hash.  Again, this is integral to how Git does change detection (among other things).  Conversely, it is *extraordinarily* unlikely that two different objects would get the same hash value (and if they did it would corrupt your repo).

So all of the things that make an object either "the same as" or "different from" another object must be taken into account when calculating that object's hash.  In the case of a commit, CommitA and CommitB could be identical in every way except that CommitA is a child of CommitX and CommitB is a child of CommitY.  They would have to be treated as different objects or you could never properly traverse history.

So when you rewrite Commit D's parent, you change the parent hash that identifies Commit D's place in history, and therefore you must rewrite Commit D (giving it a new hash as well... and this continues recursively through all descendant commits).

Comment: More details: I did the change in a separate branch, the duplicates didn't show when I pushed to that branch, it only showed when I merged with master, and when I the pull request it doesn't revert, it doesn't show any changes, is there any way to revert it?

Comment: I think there's some confusion on a couple things here... A filter-tree operation doesn't occur "on a branch", it affects all of history.  Existing branch refs are moved as necessary to conform to the new history.  As Islam Azab alluded, you may still have remote refs that point to the old branches, and maybe that's the source of the problem as you're seeing it...

Comment: ... so I originally understood you to mean that you needed others' commits not to be rewritten (i.e. to have the same hash they always had); that can only be done by not performing the filter-tree operation.  But if you just need to get the remote "on the same page" as your repo, then his answer should help you.

Comment: Lastly... yes, you can revert, using either the reflog or the saved refs in .git/refs/original to point the refs back to where they were before the filter-tree operation.